# Promise.map doesn't wait all content finish

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, bluebird

I use `Promise.map` from bluebird, and my code has following structure. The `data_array` is a list of post_id, and I want to use `fetch` to get posts from the database.

```
Promise.map(data_array, function(data_array){
    // fetch from database
    // render post
    console.log("after process")
}).then(function(){
    console.log("Done")
});
```

But the "Done" always appears before the fetch and render finish. I'm not sure if I use `Promise.map` correctly. Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: are you **returning** the promise returned by fetch in `// fetch from database` - seeing as the last line of code inside that map callback is `console.log` I suspect you are not

Comment: Thanks and now it works. But how could I extract the data_array after 
map function?

Comment: `.then(function(results) { here be the results });`

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use Promise.all instead?